# JQuery not executing - but it is loading?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've got a bit of a problem with a very simple JQuery bit of JQuery code - I've been troubleshooting it by:

1. Moving the JQuery code to the end of the document
2. Using google hosted JQuery and local hosted
3. Using the $(document).ready - and without
4. Simplifying it by taking out the PHP generated code, inserting it in a HTML document and trying it without the PHP
5. Inserting the code with firebug - note: **This actually works perfectly**

Here's the JQuery code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.del').click(function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($reports)){
        echo '<tr><th>'.$row['title'].'</th>';
        echo '<td><a href="modify.php?site='.$row['id'].'">Modify</a></td>';
        echo '<td> <img class="del" id="'.$row['id'].'" src="../right_place.jpg" width="75" height="75"></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="../report.php?site='.$row['id'].'"><img src="../'.$row['thumb'].'" width="75" height="75"></a></td></tr>';
    }
```

Which generates this kind HTML:

```
            <tr>
                <th>Site 2</th>
                <td><a href="modify.php?site=2">Modify</a></td>
                <td><img class="del" id="2" src="../right_place.jpg" width="75" height="75"></td>
                <td><a href="../report.php?site=2"><img src="../placeholder.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Site 1</th>
                <td><a href="modify.php?site=1">Modify</a></td>
                <td><img class="del" id="1" src="../right_place.jpg" width="75" height="75"></td>
                <td><a href="../report.php?site=1"><img src="../placeholder.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a></td>
            </tr>
```

I've currently tried it in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer. The most interesting aspect of this is that if I copy and paste the JQuery code in to firebug, it executes perfectly and there are no errors?! However when it is in the page it will not execute. (Hence one reason I tried putting the code at the bottom of the page!)

*Note: The JQuery code is also simplified for debugging/testing purposes - in reality it will prompt the user for confirmation before making an AJAX call to a PHP script that performs a MySQL query.*

Comment: It works perfectly at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaaKG/1/), must have something to do with your PHP code. Nore I added alt attributes to your images so that we have something to click on.

Comment: I've just tested this and it works (http://jsfiddle.net/9YdTv/ - although I changed the images to spans so I had something to click on). Is your PHP code being loaded via AJAX? If so you'll need to use either the `live()` or `delegate()` methods to hook up the events.

Comment: I've never seen jsFiddle before - nice site, cheers for pointing it out guys! It was the script tag in the end, but I'm glad I'm not the only one who overlooked it! Cheers guys for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things wrong here.

1).  Don't use numeric IDs.  IDs must begin with a letter.

2).  Your script tag is incorrect, using a language specifier instead of type specifier.  It should read:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Fix that and it should work.

Comment: Btw, I actually tested my solution for you : ), and yes... mine works.  The javascript wasn't executing at all with the old script tag.

Comment: why dont use numeric IDs? I use numeric ids in my project - no problem at all

Comment: @evgeniy.labusnkiy They break spec.  You can't rely on them to work across browsers.

Comment: @John - i finished more than 15 big project - never have any problems

Comment: @evgeniy.labusnkiy | That's the point of spec compliance.  You can always roll the dice with something that 'generally' works... but you can't test everything.  That's why you write to the spec and make modifications for the quirks, not the other way around.

Comment: Dead on with the script tag! Erghh - so simple, massive thanks! Also cheers for the tip about numeric id's; I never knew that!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove language="text/javascript" and it will work

Comment: The issue is that type="text/javascript" isn't in the code.  Op has 'language="text/javascript"'.

Comment: Yep, I've accepted John's answer as he was also right about numeric ID's - but I've up-voted you too! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your doc ready function to:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.del').live('click', function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ***[delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)*** method:

```
$(function() {

    $("img").delegate(".del", "click", function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });

});
```